# Acumatica report parameter for Branch

Tags: acumatica

How do I add a parameter for branch to a report?

I tried to copy the values from an existing report and I keep getting an error

> "Object Reference not set to an instance of an object".

I used

```
= Report.GetFieldSchema('OrganizationBranchReportParameters.BranchID, OrganizationID')
```

for the view and

```
= Report.GetDefExt('OrganizationBranchReportParameters.BranchID')
```

for default. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Compare what you have with a standard report that has a Branch parameter like AP Edit Detailed (AP610500.rpx):
[image]

Open this report with the report designer by using the EDIT REPORT button.
In the report designer open the Schema Builder with menu File->Build Schema.
Open the Parameter tab of the Schema Builder, select Branch parameter in tree view.
Follow the same pattern for your Branch Parameter, all information is in the right pane.
Substitute the APRegister DAC with your filter DAC if required.
[image]

Go to the Filter tab to use your Parameter in the query filter logic:
[image]

I suspect your issues might be caused by the use of a new custom table 'OrganizationBranchReportParameters'.
That table has to be visible in the Schema Builder Tables tab Right Pane.
If it's not in the left pane, use the Load Schema button to load the custom tables.
If it's not in the right pane, use the Arrow button to put it there.
[image]

Comment: I was using some existing reports as models for filtering by branch.  That is where I found the values I used.  All the examples I saw had company as well in the parameters and I did not.  When I added it, the error went away.  Is it needed to allow the lookup for branches within the company?

Comment: I don't think so but it's hard to tell because you only put the most basic error information in your question and the (custom?) DAC is not provided. I think at that point it depends how you crafted the DAC. And the answer could very well be in the error traces.