# How to populate list in report parameter based on any condition

Tags: acumatica

I want to populate a list of Customers in report parameter. I remember we can use something like `=Report.GetFieldSchema('ARPayment.CustomerID')`. However, I want to populate this list or say filter this list based on some conditions.

Can anyone suggest how can I do that? Is there a possibilities I can do that in Acumatica Report Desinger Parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about filtering the popup window of the selector control for the parameter in the report form:
[image]

I think these are filtered based on the DAC field used. In your case that would be 'ARPayment.CustomerID':

```
public class ARPayment : ARRegister, IInvoice, ICCPayment, IApprovable, IApprovalDescription
{
    #region CustomerID
    public new abstract class customerID : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    [CustomerActive(Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, Filterable = true, TabOrder = 2)]
    [PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<Customer.status, Equal<CR.BAccount.status.active>,
                Or<Customer.status, Equal<CR.BAccount.status.oneTime>,
                Or<Customer.status, Equal<CR.BAccount.status.hold>,
                Or<Customer.status, Equal<CR.BAccount.status.creditHold>>>>>), Messages.CustomerIsInStatus, typeof(Customer.status), ReplaceInherited = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Customer", TabOrder = 2)]
    [PXDefault()]
    public override Int32? CustomerID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._CustomerID;
        }
        set
        {
            this._CustomerID = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    […]
}
```

You could provide another DAC which has a different PXRestrictor clause to filter the customer. I think redefining the 'ARPayment.CustomerID' DAC field globally would work too but it has the side effect of changing the selector filter everywhere that field is used.

If instead what you're looking for is passing multiple values to the report in a single parameter (example: single parameter that pass an array of values) that is not directly possible to my knowledge and would require workarounds such as passing multiple values as explained here:
https://www.timrodman.com/augforums/acumatica-report-designer/multiple-values-for-a-parameter/

Comment: In that case can I customize the CustomerID field i.e. write an extension class only for report and then use that field for parameter selector. Would that be ok?

Comment: Yes, I haven't tried it but think it would be supported. The other option would be a different DAC, that seems to be the approach taken in this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52349339/acumatica-report-parameter-for-branch

Comment: Thanks HB_Acumatica. I think I would probably go with creating custom extension class.